Yocto Qt6: Qt6QuickTools dependency missing
I'm working on getting Qt6 to work on an embedded system. But I am getting the following error:
Qt6Quick could not be found because dependency Qt6QuickTools could not be found.
Could NOT find Qt6QuickTools (missing: Qt6QuickTools_DIR) 
Here is the Yocto recipe:
SUMMARY = "Qt application recipe"   
DESCRIPTION = "This recipe builds the Application"   
LICENSE = "CLOSED"   
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

DEPENDS += "qtbase qtdeclarative qtcharts qtimageformats qtscxml qtmultimedia qtquick3d"

RDEPENDS:${PN} += "qtsvg \
qtdeclarative-qmlplugins \
ttf-dejavu-sans \
ttf-dejavu-serif \
"

SRC_URI = "github url"
SRCREV = "github commit hash"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit qt6-cmake
     
do_install() {   
    install -d ${D}/opt/app/   
    install -m 0755 app ${D}/opt/app/   
    install -m 0755 ${S}/mod/setup.sh ${D}/opt/app/
    cp -r ${S}/*  ${D}/opt/app/
}   
    
FILES:${PN} += "/opt/app/* "

Here is the CMake for the Qt project:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(project VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS QuickControls2)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Qml)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Charts)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        ...
        qml.qrc
)

qt_add_executable(project
    MANUAL_FINALIZATION
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE Qt6::Core)
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE Qt6::QuickControls2)
target_link_libraries(project  PRIVATE Qt6::Charts)
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE Qt6::Qml)


if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_import_qml_plugins(project)
    qt_finalize_executable(project)
endif()

I have tried several different versions of Qt. It works fine with Qt5, but fails with Qt6. Also, the Qt6 version runs and works fine during development on Windows. I have struggled to find anything online about Qt6QuickTools.

Possibly “qtquick3d-native” is missing in the DEPENDS (because the tools are not part of the qtquick3d target recipe).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
